# Convert SQL Alter statement to MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I need to convert following SQL alter query into SQL,

**SQL :**

```
Alter table Registry
Add SndrIdQual  Char(2) NULL CONSTRAINT
[DF_Registry_PartIdQual] DEFAULT ('')
```

I tried with the following one :

**MySQL :**

```
Alter table Registry
Add SndrIdQual  Char(2) NULL DEFAULT ''
CONSTRAINT `DF_Registry_PartIdQual`;
```

but it gives me following error :

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT `DF_Registry_PartIdQual`'
```

Also I tried different cases but I did not find any solution, please help me.

When I generate a DDL query I got following

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Registry](
[UniqCode] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
[AddedAt] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
[SndrIdQual] [char](2) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
[UniqCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
UNIQUE CLUSTERED 
(
[ClmRegNum] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Registry] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Registry_UniqCode]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [UniqCode]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Registry] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Registry_PartIdQual]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [SndrIdQual]
```

GO

Comment: Your ddl is sql server can you publish the mysql ddl?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `registry` (
  `UniqCode` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AddedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UniqCode`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UQ__XRHCII_E__810DC23C29A76A3F` (`ClmRegNum`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

Comment: Now I need to add one more field named "SndrIdQual" that should follow above criteria

Answer (score 0):

May be You just need this:

```
ALTER TABLE database.table
      ADD COLUMN SndrIdQual  Char(2) NULL DEFAULT ''
```

Comment: Does not work no foreign key in my query, I am able to write the queries with the fk but in this case, they used only "CONSTRAINT" keyword which I do not understand.

Comment: in your table PartIdQual is exists or you need to create fk for partidqual..@Sagar

Comment: I added my complete DDL statement in my question and I did not find any fk.